# Vue/Vuex unknown action type

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

I have started implementing Vuex in my application and I decided to split my store into modules.

For the beginning I created only one module to test how Vuex modules works because I didn't have any previous experience with it.

I created a modules folder and inside I have one folder for my module called **Company**. Inside the company folder I have created next files: **action.js, getters.js, index.js, mutations.js**.

The code inside these files:

**action.js**:

```
import api from '@/vuex/utils/api'

const getCompanies = (context) => {
    api.get('/57/companies').then(response => {
        context.commit('GET_COMPANIES', response)
    }).catch((error) => {
        console.log(error)
    })
}

export default {
    getCompanies
}
```

*NOTE: Inside the **api** that i import i just created methods for basics operations(get,post,delete,etc...)*

**getters.js:**

```
const allCompanies = state => state.companies

export default {
    allCompanies
}
```

**mutations.js:**

```
const GET_COMPANIES = (state, companies) => {
    state.companies = companies
}

export default {
  GET_COMPANIES
}
```

**index.js:**

```
import actions from './action'
import getters from './getters'
import mutations from './mutations'

const state = {
  companies: []
}

export default {
  namespaced: true,
  state,
  actions,
  getters,
  mutations
}
```

After creation of this module I have added it to my store like this:

**store.js:**

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuex from 'vuex'
import companyModule from './modules/company'

Vue.use(Vuex)

const store = new Vuex.Store({
  modules: {
    company: companyModule
  }
})

export default store
```

*NOTE I have told my vue app to use this store inside **main.js** file*

To test this I have created simple HelloWorld component where I attempted to load the data inside simple html table. Here the problem showed up. Inside the **mounted** hook i have dispatched my action called **getCompanies** and I can see the data inside my table, its there, but i am getting error inside my dev console telling me:

> vuex.esm.js?358c:417 [vuex] unknown action type: getCompanies

Code for HelloWorld component:

```
import { mapGetters } from 'vuex'

...
 
computed: {
    ...mapGetters({
        companies: 'company/allCompanies'
     })
}

...

mounted () {
    this.$store.dispatch('company/getCompanies')
}

...
```

Data is present in my store, check screenshot from my vue devtools:
[image: vuedevtools]

> So my question is why am I getting this error inside my console, am I missing something, and how is it working with that error. Thanks!

Comment: According to screenshot, store data has been loaded successfully, so it works as expected. Are you sure that `this.$store.dispatch('getCompanies')` is not invoked anywhere else?

Comment: lol, actually you are right i was starting to question myself, i was looking for an error on completely wrong side, thanks

Comment: That's one of the reasons why `mapActions` and other helpers are great. Helps to locate store usage quite efficiently.

Comment: Yea i will check that more in depth for sure, first time using Vuex so I wasn't sure if i am doing things correctly

Comment: `module namespace`

`

      // this.$store.dispatch('doubleHundred');
      // module namespace
      this.$store.dispatch('seatSelect/doubleHundred');
`

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Try this:

```
import { mapGetters,  mapActions} from 'vuex'

computed: {
  ...mapGetters({
    companies: 'company/allCompanies'
  })
}

methods: {
  ...mapActions(['company/getCompanies', 'company/getEmployees'])
},

mounted() {
  this['company/getCompanies']();
},
```

But, I like to do namespacing as done below, but it has an issue, refer the issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55269463/1292050).

```
methods: {
  ...mapActions('company', ['getCompanies', 'getEmployees'])
},

mounted() {
  this.getCompanies();
  this.getEmployees();
},
```

Comment: After searching for a solution to this for the last 2 days, I finally found your post! Thank you for this.

Comment: notes: ES-next, `...spread`, `distructuring assingment` with rename

Answer (score 16):

When you use modules inside your store.js then take care that you use

```
export const namespaced = true
```

and **NOT**

```
export const namespaces = true
```

inside your modules/foo.js files. An ugly typo!

Answer (score 14):

You can fix it with

```
this.$store.dispatch('company/getCompanies', null, {root:true})
```

Also use `mapActions` method in the components

Comment: `{ root: true }` option works in the store nicely, this was the fix for me. I needed to dispatch an action to another store from an action handler.

Answer (score 0):

I am leaving a things to check liste.

Be sure that:

- You created your index store file with createStore function.
- You didn't create your modules with createStore function
- Your modules have the `namespaced: true`

Answer (score 0):

Actually, in my case I was doing a dumb thing which was defining my `mapActions` inside `computed` object

Answer (score -3):

Please remove namespaced: true and try again.