# How to access vue/vuex mapActions methods with similar name while has different namespace?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

This works just fine.

```
created() {
  this['shared/getPosts']();
  this['posts/getPosts']();

},

methods: {
  ...mapActions(['shared/getPosts', 'posts/getPosts']),
},
```

But, I was wondering, is there a way to make below code work as expected, please refer comment:

```
created() {
  this.getPosts(); // triggers last method
},

methods: {
  ...mapActions('shared', ['getPosts']), // how to trigger this?
  ...mapActions('posts', ['getPosts']), // this gets triggered.
},
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Just rename like so

```js
created() {
  // call the first method
  this.getSharedPosts();
  // or second
  this.getPosts();
},

methods: {
  ...mapActions('shared', {
    getSharedPosts: 'getPosts', // <-- call it as `this.getSharedPosts()` in component
  }),
  ...mapActions('posts', {
    getPosts: 'getPosts',   // <-- call it as `this.getPosts()`
  }),
},
```

More info [here](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/actions.html#dispatching-actions-in-components)

Comment: Is there no way to rename multiple actions at once?
something like:  `...mapActions('shared', [{getSharedPosts: 'getPosts'}, {getSomething: 'something'}]),`

Comment: @ShayaUlman: just pass in only one object

`...mapActions('shared', { getSharedPosts: 'getPosts', getPosts: 'getPosts' })`