# Vuex problem. this.$store.dispatch(...) working, although ...mapAction do not

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex, store

I got a problem with dispatching Actions from vuex, I don't know why, but ...mapActions do not trigger request to Jsonplaceholder. However `this.$store.dispatch` return all 10 users without any problems, so here is scripts of two files, home.vue page, and store.js:

HOME:

```js
<script>
  import { mapGetters, mapActions } from "vuex";
  export default {
    name: "Home",
    created() {
      // this.$store.dispatch('fetchUsers')
      console.log(this.$store);
    },
    computed: {
      ...mapGetters(["getUsers"])
    },
    methods: {
      ...mapActions(["fetchUsers"]),
      increment() {
        this.$store.commit("increment");
        console.log(this.$store.state.count);
      }
    }
  };
</script>
```

STORE:

```js
const store = new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    count: 0,
    users: []
  },
  getters: {
    getUsers(state) {
      return state.users;
    }
  },
  mutations: {
    increment(state) {
      state.count++;
    },
    setUsers(state, users) {
      console.log(state, users);
      state.users = users;
    }
  },
  actions: {
    fetchUsers({ commit }) {
      return new Promise(resolve => {
        fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users")
          .then(response => {
            return response.json();
          })
          .then(result => {
            console.log(result);
            commit("setUsers", result);
            return resolve;
          })
          .catch(error => {
            console.log(error.statusText);
          });
      });
    },
    incrementUsers({ commit }) {
      commit("fetchUsers");
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Few thing i am seeing not done right, anyhow, let's figure out, ping me on skype: syed_haroon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are using `mapGetters` and `mapActions` here:

```
import {mapGetters, mapActions} from 'vuex'
```

the easier way to do this is:

```
created() {
  this.fetchUsers()
  console.log(this.getUsers)
},
computed: {
  ...mapGetters(['getUsers'])
},
methods: {
  ...mapActions(['fetchUsers']),
}
```

Also, just in case if you like to use name-spacing then follow this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/55269592/1292050

Comment: A very common situation where this occurs is when someone puts `..mapActions` in their computed properties rather than in their methods. `mapActions` are functions - therefore they go in methods! `mapState` and `mapGetters` go in computed!